# Is it possible to assign global variable value with local variable value in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image: Code Snippet]

I have attached code snippet. I want to change the value of Global variable from a function variable. Is it possible?

```
create or replace package pack_testing
as
function f1(n in number) return number ;
end;

create or replace package body pack_testing
as
n number:=1;
function f1(n in number) RETURN number
is
z number:=n;
begin
 for i in 1..10 loop
                     z:=z+1;
                     if n<3 then dbms_output.put_line(i+'o');
                     else dbms_output.put_line(i);
                     end if;
                     return(i); 
                     begin
                     n:=z;   --this line giving error . I am assigning global variable value with local variable
                      end;
             end loop;
end;
end;
```

Comment: You only attach image, not code snippet.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach Now, I have attached the code snippet...

Answer (score 4):

If a subunit redeclares a global variable, you can reference the global variable by using the name of the unit that holds the global variable. In your case, just add the package name in front of the variable:

```
pack_testing.n:=z;
```

But it is best to avoid this situation entirely by using more descriptive names, not re-using names, or having a variable prefix policy. The rules around variable scope and precedence get trickier when SQL is involved, so I typically prefix every PL/SQL variable with `G_` for global, `C_` for constant, `P_` for paramter, and `V_` for (local) variable.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the same name `n` for two objects: package global variable and input paramter of function `f1`

As the matter of variable scope, your local **input paramter** of function `f1` will have more prioritize than your n global variable.

And your n paramter is IN, not OUT or IN OUT, it cannot be assign value z, so that oracle raise error. If you have a global variable `n`, then change your IN parameter to n1 or sth else, for e.g FUNCTION f1( n1 IN NUMBER)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pack_testing
AS 
    FUNCTION f1(n1 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pack_testing
AS
    n NUMBER := 1;
    
    FUNCTION f1(n1 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
    AS 
        z NUMBER := n1;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..10 
        LOOP
            z := z + 1;

            IF n < 3 
            THEN
                dbms_output.put_line(i + 'o');
            ELSE
                dbms_output.put_line(i);
            END IF;

            RETURN i;

            BEGIN
                n := z;
            END;
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;
```

And your test code seem never reach the line `n := z;` because it always end at previous line `RETURN i;`. So for the `LOOP`

Comment: As per my requirement I need to pass global variable value in function f1 as a parameter.

Comment: @prashantchhetri If that is package global variable, you don't need to pass it as parameter to function in the same package. Just use it in your function is enough.